# Indicate continuous background process in flowchart

Tags: design

I'm trying to create a flowchart of the operational process for a widget that I'm designing. What would be a good way to indicate a "background" process that occurs but can be affected by other steps in the flowchart?

For example, I want to indicate that a vehicle will drive continuously and scan for obstacles continuously. If an obstacle is detected, the vehicle will then stop driving, change direction, and then continue driving and scanning again.

How can I most effectively indicate this in a flowchart?

Comment: related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529380/how-could-i-represent-a-interrupt-for-microcontrollers-in-a-flowchart

Answer (score 1):

I use sequence function chart for PLC code design and general industrial process flow diagrams. I find that separating out parallel loops simplifies the structure and legibility.

[image]

*Figure 1. Independent process flows.*

For PLC relay ladder logic I will number each step and can then make conditional branch by referencing a step in another flow.

There is a free online charting utility at https://www.draw.io.